# Sätze mit Konj. 1 und Konj. 2 richtig verstehen

Tags: subjunctive

Ich bin beim Lesen eines Buchs auf diese Sätze gestoßen:

> Nehmen wir mal an, dieser Patient besäße einen zwanghaft perfektionistischen Charakter, hätte in seiner Familie bereits die negativen Seiten dieses Charakters kennengelernt und sich ein Stück weit von ihnen distanziert. Aus diesem Grunde ließe er nun seine Akte zu Hause, gäbe sich betont spontan und **wirke** in seinen Äußerungen und Erwartungen gut motiviert, **könne** aber auf eine Intervention nichts Neues gestalten, sondern bliebe starr und monoton bei seinem korrigierten Verhalten. (Fett-Markierung von mir — Bandabi)

In diesen zwei Sätzen fand ich folgende Konjunktiv 2 Verben:

- besäße
- hätte
- ließe
- gäbe
- bliebe

Und folgende Konjunktiv 1 Verben (fett-markiert):

- wirke
- könne

Es handelt sich um eine irreale Annahme. Ich finde deswegen Konjunktiv 2 hier passend. Ich verstehe nicht, warum "wirke" und "könne" in Konjunktiv 1 anstelle Konjunktiv 2 verwendet wurden. Ich würde mich über eine Erklärung freuen. Vielen Dank im Voraus.

Comment: Das ist meiner Meinung einfach ein Fehler. Es muss *wirkte* und *könnte* heißen.

Comment: Es ist nicht unbedingt ein Fehler, sowohl den Konjunktiv I als auch den Konjunktiv II in einem Satz zu verwenden, um eine hypothetische oder irreale Annahme auszudrücken.

Comment: Oh Mann, es ist verwirrend. Ich habe so gelernt, dass man Konjunktiv 2 für irreale Annahme oder Wünsche, Konjunktiv 1 für indirekte Rede benutzt. Ich hätte so gern eine erleuchtende Erklärung dazu.

Comment: Ein mit "Nehmen wir mal an..." eingeleiteter Nebensatz muss nicht in jedem Fall eine irreale Annahme beinhalten. Die Annahme könnte ja auch richtig sein.

Comment: @RHa Hm, okay. Annahme könnte ja auch richtig sein. Aber das ist immer so, nicht wahr? Nehmen wir mal an, dass Bandabi irgendwann ein Millionär würde. Wenn ich so etwas sage, benutze ich Konjunktiv 2 und ich nehme an, dass es so richtig wäre. Wenn ich denselben Satz mit Konj. 1 sage, klingt es falsch, oder?: Nehmen wir mal an, dass Bandabi irgendwann ein Millionär werde. Oder ist das doch richtig?

Comment: Abgesehen von der berechtigten Frage: Ich würde mir über die Konjunktive nicht allzu viele Gedanken machen. Kaum ein Muttersprachler sieht da bedeutsame Unterschiede, sofern er sie überhaupt benutzt.

Comment: @Olafant Vielen Dank für den Kommentar! Das ist echt gut zu wissen, wie die meisten Muttersprachler es wahrnehmen. Nämlich ist mein Lernziel Deutsch nur ungefähr so gut zu verstehen wie durchschnittliche Muttersprachler mit Abitur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Es geht beides, und Konjunktiv I ist bei schwachen Verben klarer

Sowohl Konjunktiv I als auch II können für hypothetische Situationen verwendet werden, auch wenn Konjunktiv II häufiger ist. Man könnte jeden Konjunktiv II mit Konjunktiv I ersetzen, und der Satz klingt weiter richtig.

Aber warum jetzt genau diese zwei Verben?
Das sind genau die schwachen Verben[1].
Ich denke, Konjunktiv I wird bei schwachen Verben verwendet, da Konjunktiv II mit Präteritum verwechselt werden kann. Wir haben hier einen ellenlangen, hypothetischen Paragraph, und müssen aufpassen, dass der Leser genau weiß, wann dieser aufhört. Also darf kein Verb nach Indikativ klingen, wie folgendes Beispiel demonstriert:

> Der Mann stellte sich vor, er hätte wieder Haar. Er wirkte wie ein Idiot.

Weil er es sich vorstellt oder in seiner Vorstellung? Viel sicherer ist es, gleich Konjunktiv I zu verwenden.

Was ist jetzt aber mit dem Ersatz mit "würden"? Das könnte so klingen, als
wäre der Teil davor, der nicht würden verwendet, das Resultat des vorigen Teils wäre.

> Nehmen wir an, der Patient hätte die negativen Seiten dieses Charakters kennengelernt. Er **würde** in seinen Äußerungen und Erwartungen gut motiviert **wirken**, aber [...].

Allerdings ist es auch und vor allem eine stilistische Frage, "würden" zu verwenden.

[1]: "können" ist ein unregelmäßiges (Präteritopräsens), aber schwaches Verb.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort. Ich wusste nicht, dass Konjunktiv 1 auch für irreale Annahmen bzw. Hypothesen verwendet werden kann. Ich habe auch in anderen Büchern, an anderen Stellen solchen Fällen gesehen, dass es so aussah, dass Konj. 1 so verwendet worden wäre, als ob das Konj. 2 wäre. Ich habe Deutschkurse bis C2 besucht und nie wurde mir das explizit gesagt. Ich wünsche Ihnen einen guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr!